# sql server as persistent db for activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic

When my activemq goes down, how can i store the message that are on its way to activemq?If the answer is using persistance db , then how and when can i resend those messages that were stored in db back to activemq queue(assuming it is up and working)?

(To give you a complete background: whenever a row gets inserted into by db my db triggers http to my java app .this app puts the changes in db as messages into activemq(we have written this thing as we are not experts in java spring frame work))

any solutions or suggestions in this regard is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is indeed persistency:
[Persistent messaging](http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html) (ensures the messages are stored in a datastore until the broker receives the acknowledgement that it has been delivered successfully to all consumers)
This will ensure the messages are re-sent (automatically) once the broker is back alive.

If you want redundancy, you should look for the [master/slave topology](http://activemq.apache.org/masterslave.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply @srodriguez.I have configured my sql db as persistence db and i the messages that had come when AMQ was down is also getting into the queue. But these messages are not getting consumed.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on your broker topology? Do you have consumers? Do you see the consumers in your queues? What kind of subscription are you using?